# Layer Blending in ArcGIS Pro and Publishing to service

Tags: arcgis-pro, wms, layers

I've been working on a service to publish and have made a very clean map using layer blending. However, when publishing as a Web Map, a web layer WMS and a Map image, it removes the blending of my layers.

Are there any settings prior to publishing that I am missing, or can it be reapplied on the front end after publishing?

TO Clarify: We are publishing to our portal page on AGOL for Organizations, version 2.8. We're using the NGA World Street Map 2d layer and a World Ocean base layer, and trying to blend using the "Multiply" blending function under darkening. We've tried using Web Map under Share and let default settings. Under sharing as a web layer we selected Map image under general and WMS under configuration. We've tried using both the base map we created for the World Street Map, and used the registered database files instead of a service

Comment: Are you publishing to ArcGIS Online for Organizations or somewhere else?  What version of ArcGIS Pro are you using?  What are the precise and detailed steps that you performed to get to where you are stuck?

Comment: We are publishing to our portal page on AGOL for Organizations, version 2.8.  We're using the NGA World Street Map 2d layer and a World Ocean base layer, and trying to blend using the "Multiply" blending function under darkening.

We've tried using Web Map under Share and let default settings. Under sharing as a web layer we selected Map image under general and WMS under configuration.

We've tried using both the base map we created for the World Street Map, and used the registered database files instead of a service.

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications and additional relevant information to what you wish to ask.